# Question about sound identifcation

Tags: discussion, topic-scope, asking-questions

Related question: https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/34985/what-is-this-sound (the question has been self-deleted)

The content is simply a sound from SoundCloud, and a question asking what it is.

Apart from the SFX is actually used for on-going contest, is identification question on-topic here?

- If it's on-topic, how should the community answer it?
- If it isn't, is there any way to salvage this kind of question?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's absolutely on-topic.  It should be answered like "That sounds like the foobar preset of the frobinator synth.  You can replicate it with these general synth settings."

That's very much sound-design, no?